# Cors error when making put request to AWS bucket

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, http-headers, http-status-code-400

I want to upload images to my AWS bucket using Pre-Signed URLs, I got the URL without any problem, but when I make put a request on it I faced this CORS problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niO40.jpg)

I tried to set my request headers as following :

```js
const res = await fetch(data, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },

      body: file
    })
 console.log(res)
```

I also made changes to my bucket rules as following but unfortunately it didn't work

```js
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "x-amz-meta-custom-header"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem is that you can't put wildcard in `AllowedOrigins`. You need to specify correct domen name. It works for me.